# Kong official docker images broken?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kong

I’m trying to run kong on docker\kubernetes and I tried a bunch of images (0.13, 0.11, 0.11,2, some of the alpine images) and all of them share the same feature. if I run `kong` inside of those nothing happens. doing `echo $?` returns 132. i tried running `/usr/local/bin/kong` but the result is the same.

Is it just me or all of those are broken?

I’m using ubuntu 16.04\windows docker hosts with one of the latest docker versions. both of them fail in this same manner.

If they are fine, please explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm running this one: `kong:0.11.2-alpine` (with a bunch of custom plugins) and it works fine...so it's more likely something on your environment. Did you check `https://hub.docker.com/_/kong/` for the supported tags?

Comment: like i said, I tried bunch of different host\images. the ones that didnt work: kong:0.11; 0.11.2; 0.11-alpine; 0.11.2-alpine; 0.12; 0.12.2, one of the RC versions. this is using 3 or 4 different ubuntu vms (fresh from Azure marketplace) and my windows laptop (both linux\windows modes)

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ take a look at the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue (no idea how to work around it at the moment though). The problem lies with the exit code 132: SIGILL – illegal instruction.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
model name      : AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 4171 HE
```

This leads us [here](https://discuss.konghq.com/t/ubuntu-linux-and-kong/51/7), which kind-of gives away the sad part: this processor doesn't support SSE 4.2. Here is the [proof](http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/753/AMD_Opteron_4100_series_4171_HE_vs_AMD_Opteron_6300_series_6378.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do to run Kong:

1. Set up a database, normally Cassandra or PostgreSQL e.g. like this:

   `docker run -d --name kong-database \
       -p 5432:5432 \
       -e "POSTGRES_USER=kong" \
       -e "POSTGRES_DB=kong" \
       postgres:9.5`
2. You need to run `kong migrations up` in a shell inside of the container once:

   `docker run --rm \
       --link kong-database:kong-database \
       -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
       -e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
       kong kong migrations up`
3. Start with the matching environment:

   `docker run -d --name kong \
   --link kong-database:kong-database \
       -e "KONG_DATABASE= postgres" \
       -e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
       -e "KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
       -e "KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
       -e "KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
       -e "KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
       -e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001" \
       -e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN_SSL=0.0.0.0:8444" \
       -p 8000:8000 \
       -p 8443:8443 \
       -p 8001:8001 \
       -p 8444:8444 \
       kong`

If you leave out the second step, kong won't start saying it needs the migrations to run.

Comment: i'm sorry, but this doesnt answer my question. it appears the binary is corrupted